# How to prevent the short menu to close before the mouse pointer move to any command inside it?

Tags: power-automate-desktop

When I use action `extract data from web page` and try to use the short menu, I move mouse pointer from `extract element value` and try to reach `src` value but the menu always close itself (**once I hover away**) . any solution ? I tested all browsers

[image]

Video for demonstration:
https://vimeo.com/791648674

Comment: Yeah, you need to simulate the click via JavaScript or something like that. I find that to be the easiest way.

Comment: No this is the short menu that appear when select "extract data from web" action

Comment: Give us a screenshot and it may make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: there is a screen shot above of the short menu

Comment: So what I said stands, use Javascript to push the button. Inspect the element, get a reference to it, push it using JS.